# STL - Why use the scope resolution operator for iterator

Tags: c++, stl

To access an STL iterator, why do I need a scope resolution operator, and not a dot operator? Is it because the iterator is static, and does not belong to a particular class instance?

```
vector<int>::iterator my_iterator;
```

and not

```
vector<int> numbers;
numbers.iterator;
```

Comment: because `vector<int>` is a type, not a variable

Comment: @AndyT the point is not that `vector<int>` is a type, but that `vector<int>::iterator` is a type and not a data member of `vector<int>`, in which case `numbers.iterator` would be correct.

Comment: @nijansen the point is that **both** `vector<int>` and `vector<int>::iterator` are types.

Comment: I think the reason is because iterators act as cursors for accessing contiguous memory space. So it makes sense that they are created as static seeing as they will do the same thing for any vector object.

Comment: @StephaneRolland you are both wrong and Andy T is correct. Only matters that vector<int> is a type.

Comment: @Iceman `numbers.iterator;` would not have sense, because one can use as many iterators as needed for a container. With your writting, there would be only one possible iterator for a container.

Comment: @Slava hey man I have +1ed Andy T's comment :-). But now more serioulsy, one cannot write `vector<int>::iterator my_iterator;`if `vector<int>::iterator` is not a type.

Comment: @StephaneRolland that irrelevant to the question, question was why :: used instead of . not will that statement work or not. So right answer is what AndyT said

Comment: If you look at what the OP wrote: ̀`numbers.iterator;` he obviously doesn't know/understand that `iterator` is a type. And I thought it was relevant to say.

Comment: @StephaneRolland ah right, missed that point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dot and arrow (`->`) operators are used to access all data (member variables, functions) that is specific to the given instance.

Scope resolution operator is used to access all data (static member variables, static functions, types) that is specific to the given type, not instance. Note that member types are never instance-specific so you will always use `type::member_type` to access them.

Answer (score 1):

`a::b` names a type; `a.b` references a variable. In your example, `my_iterator` is the variable's name, and `vector<int>::iterator` is its type.

Comment: So, :: doesn't do scope resolution, per say, here?

Comment: It doesn't matter that `vector<int>::iterator` is a type, because to access static variable you still use `::`. Only the fact that `vector<int>` is a type matters.

Comment: @Iceman: Of course it does. It indicates that `iterator` should be looked up in the scope of `vector<int>`.